# Getting a match from a list within a list and then take an index to be appended to another list

Tags: python, list

So here's the issue now:

I want to get a value from a list within a list:

```
user_test = ["user1", "123456", "500000"]
user_database = [user_test, user_test2]
```

to be more clear, "500000" from user_test, which in turn is from user_database, and then append it to another list temp=[].

But there's a condition that needs to be fulfilled:

```
if any(usr_id in item for item in user_database) and any(usr_pin in item for item in user_database):
```

So basically if a user ID and user PIN matches with a user data (in this case user_test) list from user_database, then it will take user_test[2] and then append it to temp=[]

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

### If I understand your question, then below is the solution you require:

```
# User data lists
user_test = ["user1", "123456", "500000"]
user_test2 = ["user2", "1", "200000"]
user_database = [user_test, user_test2]

# input data to match
input_user_name = "user1"
input_user_pin = "123456"

# loop through the database and match username and pin
for i in user_database:
    if f"{i[0]}{i[1]}" == input_user_name +  input_user_pin: print (i[2])

# Result --> 500000
```